# Очистить обтекание

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, всегда очищаю обтекание создавая блоки:

```
<div class="clear"></div> // clear:both
```

есть варианты очистить обтекания без создания блоков?, пробовал так:

```
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
...
<div class="row"></div>

.row{
  float: left;
}
.row:after{
  content:'';
  clear:both;
}
```

Но не сработал, хочется обойти без <div class="clear"></div>, чё то в инете не смог найти материалов

## у меня сейчас так выглядит

http://jsfiddle.net/bemulima/kx5m3/5/

хочется без

```
`<div class="clear"></div>`
```

Comment: Похоже другого варианта нет, все так решаете?

Comment: чем

    .row {
        float: left;
        clear: both;
    }

не угодил?

Comment: @Fike, если так сделать смысл тогда float:left? Ведь в таком случае все блоки в ряд станет

Comment: @bemulima, смысл тогда .row называть? .row - это ряд, строка.  
Они у вас наверняка в контейнер оборачиваются, которым можно clearfix сделать.

Comment: Не понятно чего хочет добиться автор.

Comment: @Fike, ряд - это может и не только по вертикали но и по горизонтали

Comment: @bemulima, это уже column, строка. Как лично вы называете - дело ваше, но термины уже устоявшиеся, потому я и написал не то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Посмотреть ваш пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/kx5m3/6/)**

**Стили**

```
.row + *::before {
    content:"";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: В этому случае можно было и проще:

    <img src="http://placehold.it/100.gif" />
    <span class="clear-after">Просто текст</span>
    <div>Небольшое сообщение для демонстрации работы css-свойства</div>

    img {
        margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

Comment: @FlamesoFF, мне нужно было показать работу свойства. Очевидно, что пример только для этого... Зачем его оптимизировать, убирая демонстрацию?

Comment: @VenZell, автор вообще хотел добиться другого.

Comment: @FlamesoFF, http://jsfiddle.net/bemulima/kx5m3/5/ хочу как здесь только без <div class="clear"></div>

Comment: @bemulima, готово.

Comment: @VenZell, ничего себе, круто! спасибо!